# How to handle blog tags in a contrib theme?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, theming

In blog or blog-like sites, taxonomy is often used for tags and categories.

In Drupal 6, node.tpl.php files could use the $taxonomy variable if they needed access to an array of unrendered taxonomy links associated with the current node. This variable was often assumed by contrib themes to contain the post tags and\or categories, and it was rendered accordingly.

In Drupal 7, $taxonomy is no longer available.

What's the alternative? How should themers handle taxonomy? In particular, how should contrib themes do it, in order to maximally preserve visual compatibility with the 6.x version?

BTW, the bit about that in the ["converting themes to Drupal 7"](http://drupal.org/update/themes/6/7#taxonomy) guide is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

To print the the default taxonomy field separate from the other content:

```
<?php
  <div class="content">
    hide($content['field_tags']);
    print render($content);
  </div>
  <div class="terms">
    print render($content['field_tags']);
  </div>
?>
```

This will only handle the default "tags" taxonomy. To follow discussion of an easier way to accomplish this, see [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/978242).

Answer (score 0):

We can use [taxonomy-term.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy-term.tpl.php/7) in our theme to theme the display of terms. Below are term related variables,

- $term_url: Direct URL of the current term.
- $term_name: Name of the current term.
- $name: the (sanitized) name of the term.
- $content: An array of items for the content of the term (fields and
  description). Use render($content) to print them all, or print a subset such as render($content['field_example']). Use hide($content['field_example']) to temporarily suppress the printing of a given element.